# Side by side div using inline-block not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using the radio slider as given here: [Radio Slider](http://cssdeck.com/labs/ufct35ys5t).
I want to put a dropdown on the right side of this slider, which I'm doing using `display:inline-block` like this:

```
    <div class="wrapper toggle_radio" style="background: #497dd0; display:inline-block;">
       <input type="radio" class="toggle_option" id="first_toggle" name="toggle_option">
       <input type="radio" checked class="toggle_option" id="second_toggle" name="toggle_option">
       <input type="radio" class="toggle_option" id="third_toggle" name="toggle_option">
       <label for="first_toggle"><p>All</p></label>
       <label for="second_toggle"><p>Month</p></label>
       <label for="third_toggle"><p>Quarter</p></label>
       <div class="toggle_option_slider"> </div>
     </div>

  <!-- Right side dropdown -->    
     <div class="pull right" style=" margin-left: 100px;, margin-top: 0px; display:inline-block;">
       <select placeholder="Category" ng-model="selectedCategory" class="md-dark" style="min-width: 100px;">
         <option ng-value="category" ng-repeat="category in categories">{{category | capitalize}}</option>
       </select>
     </div>
```

However, it's not properly aligned (they are on different vertical positions):
[image]

Is there any quick fix for this ?

Comment: Are you using Twitter Bootstrap?

Comment: @AbhashUpadhyaya there are no bootstrap classes in his example.

Comment: No, I'm using angular material

Comment: Tried applying vertical-align: middle; to both elements?

Comment: vertical-align worked. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Put it in a table.

Should work perfectly but you may need to make some minor tweaks (such as increasing the size of td, for example) as I've not tested the code myself. Tell me how it goes and if you need any help.

Answer (score 1):

check if:
    elements are floated or not.
    make sure their total height (*line-height, padding and margin*) is equal.
use:
    vertical-align: middle;

if you are using floats, vertical-align will not have any effect on floated elements. As display:inline-block is not useful if you are floating elements.

```
<!-- Right side dropdown -->    
 <div class="pull right" style=" margin-left: 100px;, margin-top: 0px;
```

remove that comma after margin-left:100px;

small example for not using floats.

```
<style>
    .row{
        position:relative;
        display:block;
    }
    .column{
        display:inline-block;
        width:49%;
    }
</style>

<div class="row">
    <div class="column">this is left column</div>
    <div class="column">this is right column</div>
</div>
```